# VS 2010 pc backup coding

Tags: asp.net, backup

I have a request to do something that I am not sure is possible. The request is to create a website that will backup someones PC, either through the internet or they would download a small software package that will back up their pc and send the backup to a remote server, kind of like Carbonite or Iron Mountain. Does anyone have any idea where I need to start with this or look into how to code for this.

Comment: You will have to have something running locally to grab the data.  This is a pretty complex task depending on what you consider a "backup" -- the right way (assuming Windows) would be to use the Volume Snapshot Service and then back up files (or blocks) based on those snapshots.  There are libraries for interacting with the VSS and getting that data.  That does not, however, begin to talk about restore, which (depending on your requirements) could involve some pretty low-level code.

Comment: in this instance, "backup" means basically an entire HDD backup, of either Windows or Mac. Which libraries shoudl I look at? and what is meant by low-level code? Is that machine language code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look into the existing HDD image creators (quick googling gave me [XXClone](http://www.xxclone.com/), but you may need something else).

You basically need to

1. create an image of the entire PC's storage (i.e. all logical disks)
2. upload the image to the internet area

A relatively small program may perform the tasks 1 and 2 for you, provided that you bundle it with an existing image creator.

Comment: Would you know where I can look online on how to code for such a thing.

Comment: I have done a google search of how to code for such a thing but I think I am not searching correctly because everything that comes up is pre made software

Comment: That's probably because it might be a bad idea to reinvent the wheel, especially since there are a lot of wheels that might suit you :)

Anyway, I can't help you find a way to code the thing yourself

Comment: Ok, well I spoke to my clent and talked him down from reinventing the wheel, as it was not feasible nor doable based on numerous aspects. Instead I talked him into allowing his clients to back up folders and files (personal, not windows or high security windows files and folders). Quick question, just a thought, is it possible to perform a back up of these files and folder structures that the clients choose, and back them up into a single backup file?

Comment: Yes, any archiver is capable of this. And there are libraries zip at least, so you can write your own archiver